# How to add code snippet plugin to CKEditor in Angular

Tags: angular, ng-ckeditor

I have installed [ng2-CKEditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor) on my Angular project

```
npm install ng2-ckeditor --save
```

with the following config :

```
  public getConfigOfCKEditor(): any {
    const toolbarGroups = [
      '/',
      { name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'doctools', 'document'] },
      { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing'] },
      { name: 'forms', groups: ['forms'] },
      '/',
      { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'] },
      { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph'] },
      '/',
      { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'] },
      { name: 'links', groups: ['links'] },
      { name: 'styles', groups: ['styles'] },
      { name: 'colors', groups: ['colors'] },
      { name: 'tools', groups: ['tools'] },
      { name: 'others', groups: ['others'] },
      { name: 'about', groups: ['about'] },
      { name: 'insert', groups: ['codesnippet'] }
    ];
    const removeButtons: string = 'Source,Templates,Save,NewPage,Print,Replace,Scayt,SelectAll,Form,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Blockquote,CreateDiv,Language,Image,Flash,Table,HorizontalRule,Smiley,SpecialChar,PageBreak,Iframe,ShowBlocks,About,Checkbox,Find,Preview,Styles,Format,Anchor';

    return {
      toolbarGroups: toolbarGroups,
      removeButtons: removeButtons,
      codeSnippet_theme: 'school_book',
      codeSnippet_languages: { javascript: 'JavaScript', php: 'PHP' }
    };
  }
```

my app.component.html :

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="ckeditorContent" [config]="this.config" [readonly]="false"
    debounce="500">
</ckeditor>
```

Know, How can I add the code snippet plugin to the CKEditor ?

**NOTE:** [CodeSnipet](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/codesnippet.html) Plugin Documentation

[**Stackblitz Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjityq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `4.9.2` version of ckeditor:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.9.2/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

and then:

```
  public getConfigOfCKEditor(): any {
    const toolbarGroups = [
      '/',
      { name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'doctools', 'document'] },
      { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing'] },
      { name: 'forms', groups: ['forms'] },
      '/',
      { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'] },
      { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph'] },
      '/',
      { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'] },
      { name: 'links', groups: ['links'] },
      { name: 'styles', groups: ['styles'] },
      { name: 'colors', groups: ['colors'] },
      { name: 'tools', groups: ['tools'] },
      { name: 'others', groups: ['others'] },
      { name: 'about', groups: ['about'] },
      { name: 'insert', groups: ['codesnippet'] }
    ];
    const removeButtons: string = 'Source,Templates,Save,NewPage,Print,Replace,Scayt,SelectAll,Form,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Blockquote,CreateDiv,Language,Image,Flash,Table,HorizontalRule,Smiley,SpecialChar,PageBreak,Iframe,ShowBlocks,About,Checkbox,Find,Preview,Styles,Format,Anchor';

    return {
      toolbarGroups: toolbarGroups,
      removeButtons: removeButtons,
      disableNativeSpellChecker: false,
      ignoreEmptyParagraphValue: true,
      extraPlugins: "codesnippet", <-----------------
      codeSnippet_theme: 'school_book',
      codeSnippet_languages: { javascript: 'JavaScript', php: 'PHP' }
    };
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyrisr?file=src%2Findex.html

Hope it helps!